# Htaccess Rewrite second rule not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite urls like **index.php?c=4** & **index.php?g=23** into **website.com/games/categoryname/id/**
and the same thing for the game page **website.com/play/gamename/id/**

my htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_%]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_%]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?c=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_%]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_%]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?g=$3
```

The problem is that only the first rewrite rule is working, if I comment it, then the second will work too, but never both :(. I'm testing this on MAMP

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They cannot work both as they have the same condition - you have set two different actions with the same criteria and only the first one is executed.

Ah, I understood what you are trying to achieve:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(games)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_%]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?c=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(play)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_%]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?g=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^play/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_%]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?c=$2
RewriteRule ^games/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_%]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?g=$2
```

Comment: It is a good idea to place a `[L]` (last) after each `RewriteRule`

Comment: @Alexander Ivanov I agree, that's a good practice, although you could want more rewrite rules after these, so it depends on the situation.

Comment: Well it would be bad if he placed a rule to match for example a username after these like `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?user=$1` - that would mess up badly...

Comment: I was thinking more of something like `RewriteRule (.*)/index.php $1/`, although, one could argue this should be placed before the other rules.